# Caliburn micro: get page navigation mode in view model

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro, win-universal-app

I am using Caliburn micro in Windows Universal Apps. Is there a way to find out the page navigation mode (Back, Forward) in View Model?

In Silverlight apps we could get that in `OnNavigatedTo` event `if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)`. Is there anything equivalent available in Caliburn Micro?

Comment: Are you asking if you can find the direction from which you went or could go?  the only options in the INavigationService are CanGoForward, CanGoBack, GoForward(), GoBack(), you also have access to the respective stacks.  Although since the method is virtual you might be able to do what you asking for with OnNavigating with an override

Comment: @mvermef I need to know how the current page got loaded. Was it due to back navigation (i.e. user pressed the hardware back key) or its a new navigation (i.e. user tapped on any element in previous page which resulted in navigation to the current page)

Comment: in that case you can tap into the system with INavigationService events and check based on start or completion using Navigating or Navigated there are a couple of others as well as BackPressed (WP specific)